# how to add +7 hours in my twitter android application using json

Tags: android, json, twitter

```
for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            if (jo.getString("from_user").equalsIgnoreCase(namajalur))
            {

                if (jo.getString("text").contains(object))
                {
                    listItems.add("@" + jo.getString("from_user")+ " : \n" +jo.getString("text") + "\r\n" +
                    jo.getString("created_at"));
```

in **("created_at")** is US default timezone, its different 7 hours from my local time..

how to add +7 hours so if the default time 11:00:00 will be 18:00:00.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step by step way to achieve that would be:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

String createdAt =  jo.getString("created_at"));
Date date = new Date(Date.parse(createdAt));

String localeTime = dateFormat.format(date);
```

localeTime is your local time,you can change the format as you please.

A shorter way would be simply doing

```
listItems.add("@" + jo.getString("from_user")+ " : \n" +jo.getString("text") + "\r\n" +
                new Date(Date.parse(jo.getString("created_at"))).toLocaleString();
```

but that way you are using a deprecated method,not really the best way.

If you use simpleDate format it will parse and format it correctly,however if either you use the date the Json gives you,or you convert it to Locale,you should format it nonetheless.

Comment: thank you master bro,, that's very help me,, it works,,, ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the String value in the json (created_at) to date, use the function below and convert back to String

```
public static Date addSevenHours(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
    Date end = cal.getTime();
    return end;
}
```